# Remove Google+ profile from Gmail contact?

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts

I use the web interface for Gmail regularly and recently noticed that one of my contacts (let's call him `Jim Smith`) has a Google+ account attached to his email address...and I cannot remove the damn thing! It might be OK if his Google+ account had the name `Jim Smith`, but unfortunately he has decided to give his Google+ account the quirky name `Metal Raw-Star`, dunno why.

The big problem now comes when I try to type an email. In the `To` field, none of the following find my contact:

```
* Jim
* Smith
* Jim Smith
```

Even though this is the contact name! If I type `Metal` or `Raw` then Gmail finds the contact and inserts the email address.

If you look at the image below, I've named my contact (green), but when I enter his email (pink) Google links to the Google+ profile (blue)...and I cannot email the contact by his actual name anymore!

[image: Gmail contact linked to Google+ profile with different name]

This Google+ profile is confusing and not relevant to me. How can I unlink it from my contact? I have tried creating a new contact, but the instant I type in his email, the Google+ profile gets reconnected to the contact. This might all just be an annoyance if Gmail would just let me find my contact by the name I have assigned to him. I do not have control over what he decides to name his Google+ profile.

Comment: Looks like I've found a partial solution. In the Contact, add a `Nickname` to the contact with the text `Jim Smith`. Return to Gmail and you will now be able to find the contact by name. Return to the contact and delete the `Nickname` field and the contact should still work. The Google+ profile is still linked, though.

Comment: Looks like I stumbled on part of the answer because the accepted answer to this SuperUser question (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/gmail-strangely-switching-out-gmail-contact-information-to-google-information?rq=1) has basically the same advice => Add a `Nickname`!

Comment: This is amazing. Basically you can link a random photo to anyone's profile without their permission, as long as they don't already use G+?

Answer (score 4):

This post helped me with the same problem: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/guDL_NmcTk4

Basically, I used the old Contacts UI to change contact name.

1. Open Gmail Contacts
2. On the left side, click *More*
3. Click *Leave the Contacts preview* (this brings you to old UI)
4. Edit contact
5. Save

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

1. Just go to the linked Google+ profile and set "Block profile" (next to "About me").
2. Reload your Contacts-Page.
3. Now there's no connection between your contact and the wrong Google+ profile.

Comment: This is only  the new Google+, right?

Comment: Did not do it for me.

Answer (score 3):

The other suggestions did not work for me. I could only make it work by doing the following:

1. Block the person's Google profile: open Google+ (https://plus.google.com),
   open the profile of the person you want to block, click "More" (the three vertical dots, on the bottom) and then Block or Block profile;
2. Delete the existing contact in your Gmail Contacts (copy the email address!);
3. Create a new contact (add them to Groups if they were in there);
4. Sign out of Gmail;
5. Sign in to Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I added a contact, name N and email correct. His google+ page is fine, name is N. But his company C has a google+ page also and his email was the contact email, the page had a company logo.  Whenever i addressed an email and typed in his name in the TO field it changed to the company name C and company logo, not his real name.

I solved it my going to google contacts web page, and searching for his name. The search listed my contact entry and the company google+ entry. I deleted the company entry. The contact was not changed, and emails addressed to him now shows his name N, no company logo.

I tried the nick name thing (suggested here) and it didn't work in this case. Made no difference.